# How to show post title outside of loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I am using following codes to show title of a post in another post.But it shows only post id.How to solve this?

```
<?php $home_team_name = rwmb_meta( 'pb_select_home_team', 'type=select_advanced', get_the_ID() ); ?>
      <?php  echo esc_html( $home_team_name  ); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: This is clearly Wordpress related. How do 3 mods close this for being off topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you're outside the loop, you'll need to either know the post id of the title you want and specify it in the function parameter, or call the global $post variable if you're on the page (just not in the loop yet).

```
global $post

echo get_the_title($post->ID);

or

echo get_the_title(2);
```

Comment: When I am using echo get_the_title('3592'); then it shows the title.But my problem is not solved yet.Let me explain my problem once again.I have a custom post name 'football_team'.I have shown all post related to that CP as metabox using 'select_advanced' type in another CPT football_fixture.  Now I want to show the content I select from the metabox.Thanks

Comment: If it's returning the post id, then it should be as simple as, `echo get_the_title($home_team_name)`

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use `the_title()` or `echo get_the_title()` to print title

try

```
echo get_the_title();
```

or

```
echo get_the_title( get_the_ID() );
```

Comment: `get_the_ID()` still only works within the loop. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

Comment: @JeremyRoss you are absolutely correct, but when we access a post/page it is a loop itself. so when we call `get_the_ID()` inside of page.php or single.php `get_the_ID()` gives the id of current post/page

Comment: as @Arif Hossin can access `get_the_ID()` he can also access `get_the_title( get_the_ID() );` No need to to define `global $post`

Comment: The title of the question was how to get access from outside the loop, but I see now that in the description, that code is actually running in the loop.

Comment: It sure does is.